# Как получить все записи с определенным значением в поле JSONB?

Tags: json, postgresql

В PostgreSQL 9.4 имеется таблица с записями. Поле tags имеет тип JSONB.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить, например, все записи у которых в поле tags имеется значение 1. Ниже привожу код и ошибку, которую он вызывает.

```
SELECT public.mytable.* FROM public.mytable WHERE tags ? 1;
```

> ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb ? integer LINE 1: SELECT
>   public.mytable.* FROM public.mytable WHERE tags ? 1; 
>   ^ 
>   HINT: No
>   operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need
>   to add explicit type casts.
>   ********** Ошибка **********
>
> ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb ? integer SQL-состояние: 42883
>   Подсказка: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s).
>   You might need to add explicit type casts. Символ: 52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from (select '[1,14,5]'::jsonb as q) as foo where q @> '[1]'::jsonb;
     q      
------------
 [1, 14, 5]
```

Comment: не забудь создать gin-овый индекс с jsonb_path_ops